# Random number generator, C++

Tags: c++, random

I know there is a bit of limitations for a random number generation in C++ (can be non-uniform). How can I generate a number from 1 to 14620?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you now even look up how to use random numbers in C++? You also failed to state if you needed a better solution to built in random numbers in C++ or just being told how to use rand.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean with "limitations for a random number generation" specific to c++? More or less uniform sequences come from better or worse generators.

Comment: If rand() was (can be non-uniform) then it would not be much use.

Comment: @thecoshman: yes, I did look it up, but I could not figure out how to make them truly random in the sense of the uniform distribution.

Comment: @notroackstar then rehaps your question should state you want truly random numbers, or at least a non-uniform distribution

Comment: i think he wants a uniform distribution. my suggestion look up the book "numerical recipes in c++".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A common approach is to use [`std::rand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) with a modulo:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

// ...
std::srand(std::time(0));  // needed once per program run
int r = std::rand() % 14620 + 1;
```

However, as @tenfour mentions in his answer, the modulo operator can disrupt the uniformity of values `std::rand()` returns. This is because the modulo translates the values it discards into valid values, and this translation might not be uniform. For instance, for `n` in `[0, 10)` the value `n % 9` translates `9` to `0`, so you can get zero by either a true zero or a 9 translated to zero. The other values have each only one chance to yield.

An alternative approach is to translate the random number from `std::rand()` to a floating-point value in the range `[0, 1)` and then translate and shift the value to within the range you desire.

```
int r = static_cast<double>(std::rand()) / RAND_MAX * 14620) + 1;
```

Answer (score 20):

If you've got a c++0x environment, a close derivative of the boost lib is now standard:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> d(1, 14620);
    std::mt19937 gen;
    std::cout << d(gen) << '\n';
}
```

This will be fast, easy and high quality.

You didn't specify, but if you wanted floating point instead just sub in:

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<> d(1, 14620);
```

And if you needed a non-uniform distribution, you can build your own piece-wise constant or piece-wise linear distribution very easily.

Comment: Note that there is an important difference between the uniform int and uniform real distributions. The uniform int distribution returns numbers in the `closed range` [1,14620] while the uniform real distribution returns numbers in the `half-open range` [1,14620).

Comment: Could use the C++0x-esque seeding too, `std::random_device r; std::mt19937 gen(r());`

Comment: And if you don't have C++0x, boost::random should probably be your standard unless you really only need something quick and dirty...

Answer (score 12):

`srand() / rand()` are the functions you need, as others have answered.

The problem with `%` is that the result is decidedly non-uniform. To illustrate, imagine that `rand()` returns a range of 0-3. Here are hypothetical results of calling it 4000 times:

```
0 - 1000 times
1 - 1000 times
2 - 1000 times
3 - 1000 times
```

Now if you do the same sampling for `(rand() % 3)`, you notice that the results would be like:

```
0 - 2000 times
1 - 1000 times
2 - 1000 times
```

Ouch! The more uniform solution is this:

`int n = (int)(((((double)std::rand()) / RAND_MAX) * 14620) + 1);`

Sorry for the sloppy code, but the idea is to scale it down properly to the range you want using floating point math, and convert to integer.

Comment: '(((double)std::rand()) / RAND_MAX)' - can you please explain this part here? Are you generating random number and then scaling it by RAND_MAX?

Comment: by dividing by `RAND_MAX`, you are generating a uniform random number between 0.0 and 1.0. This makes it simple to scale to whatever bounds you want. In your case, 1-14620.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to eliminate the intermediate `double`; the end result is an `int` like you want. I do not know an integer-only answer other than using `%` as others have suggested.

Comment: nice use of casting to keep the resolution as high as possible, though would like to see C++ casting used.

Answer (score 4):

Use [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/).

```
( rand() % 100 ) is in the range 0 to 99
( rand() % 100 + 1 ) is in the range 1 to 100
( rand() % 30 + 1985 ) is in the range 1985 to 2014

( rand() % 14620 + 1 ) is in the range 1 to 14620
```

EDIT:

As mentioned in the link, the randomizer should be seeded using `srand` before use.  A common distinctive value to use is the result of a call to `time`.

Comment: You left out the important addendum: *Notice though that this modulo operation does not generate a truly uniformly distributed random number in the span*

Comment: Right, not without seeding.  The link mentions seeding at the bottom of the page.  I'll update to include this.

Comment: @James, @meagar, How would I generate truly uniform distributed random number? I have to generate 30,000 of them within just one loop of the algorithm.

Comment: @meager I have to admit I wasn't aware about that and further have to admit I don't understand why - at least not right now.

Comment: @sstn: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator has some information on why a seed is necessary.

Comment: @notrockstar: Using `rand` with a good seed is usually good enough. 'True' random numbers require more creativity, like using numbers generated by processing atmospheric noise (RANDOM.org does this).  See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/truerandom.aspx as an example.

Comment: @James I think I got it now that I am thinking about it - taking an 'artifically' generated randomly distributed set of numbers and cutting out a part (with a modulo operator) will affect the distribution.

Answer (score 2):

As already said, you can use [rand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/). E.g.

`int n = rand() % 14620 + 1;`

does the job, but it is non-uniform.
That means some values (low values) will occur slightly more frequently. This is because `rand()` yields values in the range of 0 to `RAND_MAX` and `RAND_MAX` is generally not divisible by 14620. E.g. if `RAND_MAX == 15000`, then the number 1 would be twice as likely as the number 1000 because `rand() == 0` and `rand() == 14620` both yield `n==1` but only `rand()==999` makes `n==1000` true.

However, if 14620 is much smaller than `RAND_MAX`, this effect is negligible. On my computer `RAND_MAX` is equal to 2147483647. If `rand()` yields uniform samples between 0 and RAND_MAX then, because 2147483647 % 14620 = 10327 and 2147483647 / 14620 = 146886, `n` would be between 1 and 10328 on average 146887 times while the numbers between 10329 and 14620 would occur on average 146886 times if you draw 2147483647 samples.
Not much of a difference if you ask me.

However, if `RAND_MAX == 15000` it would make a difference as explained above.
In this case some earlier posts suggested to use

`int n = (int)(((((double)std::rand()) / RAND_MAX) * 14620) + 1);`

to make it 'more uniform'.
Note that this only changes the numbers that occur more frequently since `rand()` still returns 'only' `RAND_MAX` distinct values.
To make it really uniform, you would have to reject any integer form `rand()` if it is in the range between 14620*int(RAND_MAX/14620) and RAND_MAX and call `rand()` again.
In the example with `RAND_MAX == 15000` you would reject any values of `rand()` between 14620 and 15000 and draw again.
For most application this is not necessary. I would worry more about the randomness of `rand()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial using the boost library http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html#boost_random.tutorial.generating_integers_in_a_range

Answer (score 1):

The rand() function is not really the best Random generator, a better way would be by using CryptGenRandom().

This example should do do the trick:

```
#include <Windows.h>

// Random-Generator
HCRYPTPROV hProv;
INT Random() {
    if (hProv == NULL) {
        if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_SILENT | CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
            ExitProcess(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int out;
    CryptGenRandom(hProv, sizeof(out), (BYTE *)(&out));
    return out & 0x7fffffff;
}

int main() {
    int ri = Random() % 14620 + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the modulus operator is the most important, you can apply a limit with this modulus, check this out:

```
// random numbers generation in C++ using builtin functions
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <iomanip>

using std::setw;

#include <cstdlib>   // contains function prototype for rand

int main()
{
// loop 20 times
for ( int counter = 1; counter <= 20; counter++ ) {

    // pick random number from 1 to 6 and output it
    cout << setw( 10 ) << ( 1 + rand() % 6 );

    // if counter divisible by 5, begin new line of output
    if ( counter % 5 == 0 )
        cout << endl;

}

return 0;  // indicates successful termination

} // end main
```